# Merging two groups with textbox and tablix together in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, grouping

I am facing formatting problem in generating SSRS report. I am having two groups in my report, one group is on `list` and other on `tablix`.

The first group with list contains only a textbox which display say AccountNo, while the other group has the entire table which displays the account details (AcctNo, AcctName, Type etc.).

I want to merge this two groups together, such that on each page I can see the both the groups, i.e., textbox the one with AcctNo and other with the table with acct details.

I am getting the first group on different page followed by the other group.

Can anyone suggests me how to merge these two group together on one page?

Answer (score 0):

if possible in the table, the easiest way would be to create a parent group for the two groups, so both groups would have the same parent group